# Loop to create matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a loop which will create a matrix of appropriate size. I need the matrix to be constructed of a specified number of elements which are pulled from another matrix and added together.

Here is some psuedo code:

```
    '

        n=10
        for x=1:1:n

            Kglobal=zeros(nxn)


        Kglobal(1,1)=1
        Kglobal(x+1,x+1)=Klocalx(2,1)
        Kglobal(x+1,x+2)=Klocalx(2,2)+Klocalx+1(1,1)'
if Kglobal(x+1,x+2)=(n+1,n)
   Kglobal(n,n)=Klocaln(2,2)
    end
end
```

When finished resulting in something like:

```
'  
 Kglobal=[ 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
        Klocal1(2,1) Klocal1(2,2)+Klocal2(1,1) 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
        0 Klocal2(2,1) Klocal2(2,2)+Klocal3(1,1) 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
        0 0 Klocal3(2,1) Klocal3(2,2)+Klocal4(1,1) 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
        0 0 0 Klocal4(2,1) Klocal4(2,2)+Klocal5(1,1) 0 0 0 0 0 0;
        0 0 0 0 Klocal5(2,1) Klocal5(2,2)+Klocal6(1,1) 0 0 0 0 0;
        0 0 0 0 0 Klocal6(2,1) Klocal6(2,2)+Klocal7(1,1) 0 0 0 0;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 Klocal7(2,1) Klocal7(2,2)+Klocal8(1,1) 0 0 0;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Klocal8(2,1) Klocal8(2,2)+Klocal9(1,1) 0 0;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Klocal9(2,1) Klocal9(2,2)+Klocal10(1,1) 0;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Klocal10(2,1) Klocal10(2,2)];
'
```

Thanks!! I appreciate any help and will be checking frequently so if there is something I can try to explain better please let me know!

Comment: Klocal would be a 2x2 matrix and the values are based on the calculation I am performing for each point in the matrix. I can provide that but for example (2,1) would simply be a value like Klocal(2,1)=-110.

Comment: so Klocal would look like                                           [100,-110;                                                             -110,1200]

Comment: If it helps the values of that matrix are calculated invdividually...so maybe I could make them a function of x? Currently it is set up like K11=eqn K12=eqn K21=eqn K22=eqn so maybe there is way to make those a function of the counter so I can call the right equation?

Comment: You might want to make your KlocalNN matrices part of a cell array instead, then you can iterate over them: Klocal{1} = fun(1, ..); Klocal{2} = fun(2, ...); This is cleaner than appending numbers to variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a matrix like that is quite simple using the [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html) function. For example,

```
a=1:5;
b=6:10;
c=spdiags([a',b'],[-1,0],5,5);
```

creates a sparse matrix that looks like this

```
 6     0     0     0     0
 1     7     0     0     0
 0     2     8     0     0
 0     0     3     9     0
 0     0     0     4    10
```

except that memory is allocated only for the non-zero elements. This should answer your question as to how to create such a matrix.

However, the question is, how do you get the `a`'s and `b`'s, which in your case are the bunch of `Klocal` matrices. It is not very clear as to what you're doing in your code. I'm guessing that they can be done as some compact matrix/cell operations, but cannot comment further with what's given.

Anyway, assuming you already have the `Klocal` matrices, this should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were correct it can be done using cells. Alex explained how that would work. I am fairly new to Matlab programming. I have used it much more for calculations and simulink.